# Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'desc'

Tags: python

I have this code for my class but I cant seem to import a class function from another python module I made.

classes_sub.py

```
    class Motherboard:
kind = ""
desc = ""

def __init__(self, name, desc):
    self.name = name
    self.desc = desc

def get_kind_m(self):
    return self.kind
def get_desc_m(self):
    return self.desc

    class anotherone(Motherboard):
kind = "anotherone"
desc = "anotherone"

    class Neal(Motherboard):
kind = "Neal"
desc = "Neal"
```

main.py, the function calling from another class

```
    def show_m():

import lists
reload(lists)
motherboard_l = lists.motherboard_l
global calls, key_name
calls.grid_forget()
tab = Frame(main, width = 30)
tab.grid(columnspan=4)
def new_label():
    text_m = Motherboard.get_desc_m(key_name)
    label2.configure(text=text_m)
n_of_b = len(motherboard_l)
n_of_l = 0
for i in range(n_of_b):
    key_name = motherboard_l[n_of_l]
    label1 = button(tab, text=key_name, width=15, command=new_label)
    label1.grid(rowspan=1, column=0)        
    n_of_l+=1
label2 = label(tab, text="Click Any Item to See Details",)
label2.grid(row=1, column=1)
calls = tab
```

sorry to bother anyone

Comment: Can you try writing `from classes_sub import Motherboard` in your "main.py" before your function definition?

Comment: Hi @idnanimo, your question and code is in need of [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: what i have in my code is from classes_sub import * cause i have other classes in classes_sub.py file but none of them works when their functions gets called in my main.py file

Comment: @TrebuchetMS i know, i'm sorry to confuse anyone

Comment: see this line: `text_m = Motherboard.get_desc_m(key_name)` You didn't have a `Motherboard` instance, and I think the `key_name` is not a `Motherboard` instance either.

Comment: Whether `key_name` is a `Motherboard` would depend on what `lists.motherboard_l` is. (Although the error seems to be telling us that it's a string.)

Comment: I figured it out thanks for giving me the idea @TrebuchetMS